# pytorch installation problem with conda and pip

Tags: python, pip, conda

I have problem over installation of pytorch by pip install

```
    pip install torch==1.5.0 torchvision==0.6.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

and I faced

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.5.0 (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.5.0
```

then Installed anaconda and tried installing it on "allusers" and "this user" or  with and without "add to path" option, none of them but every time I received  faced

```
failed to create process.
Failed to create temp directory "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Temp\conda-<RANDOM>\"
```

by `conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch` conda code and change the environmental variable temp or TMP to c:\temp also didnt work.
so is there any solution for repairing pip install or conda install?
and btw is this problem tempo because of my Python version[=3.8.2] and it is because of PyPi lack of support for this version or problem is within my windows parameters?

Comment: Are you using Conda? If so, you must be careful when using pip, see for example https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment. _change the environmental variable temp or TMP to c:\temp also didnt work._ What, why? _so is there any solution for repairing pip install or conda install?_ You will likely have to reinstall Conda.

Comment: thanks for warning of pip.
I had reinstalled anaconda several times.
I tried to change the environmental variable temp or TMP to c:\temp because of `Failed to create temp directory "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Temp\conda-<RANDOM>\"` error.
###solution###finally it seems all problems can be solved with `python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel` command which ensures pip, setuptools, and wheel are up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the conda installation at [pytorch.org](https://pytorch.org/get-started) that are by far the best way to install pytorch.

The cpu-only installation example is given below. All other examples are available on the website.

```
conda install pytorch torchvision cpuonly -c pytorch
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have some problems with installing libraries for conda, `conda-forge` usually solves them :)

```
conda install -c packagename conda-forge
```